# In App Purchase works on all devices expect iPad Air 2 running 8.1.2

Tags: ios, ipad, in-app-purchase

really frustrating ,
Apple reject my app with the following msg :

```
Thank you for your response. We found that the In App Purchase is not accessible when reviewed on iPad Air 2 running iOS 8.1.2, on Wi-Fi and cellular networks.
```

**viewdidload :**

```
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments(){
            let productID:NSSet = NSSet(object:"removeads")
            let request:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID)
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()
        }
```

IAP works perfectly on other devices , no idea why it dosen't work on iPad air running 8.1.2

i made some debugging from img they sent me , and the error appear to be that on this particular case , the IAP data that should return the product identifier for making the purchase , dosent retrieve . So when the press the Remove Ads button it dosent do anything , My code if it helps :

The remove ads button :

```
   if isConnectedToNetwork()
        {
            btn_removeads.enabled = false
        let payment:SKPayment = SKPayment(product: product)
            if payment.productIdentifier != nil {
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment)
            }
            else {
                btn_removeads.enabled = true
                presentViewController(alert2, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**// This is the error that poping , the data havent received yet.**

```
            }
        }
        else {

            presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
```

**REST OF IAP CODE :**

```
 func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!){
        let products = response.products
        if products.count != 0
        {
            product = products[0] as SKProduct

        }
    }

    func getProductInfo(){
        if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments(){
            let productID:NSSet = NSSet(object:"removeads")
            let request:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID)
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()
        }
    }

    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!){
        for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
            if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
                switch trans.transactionState {
                case .Purchased:
                    btn_removeads.enabled = true

                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(1, forKey: "ifads")
                    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = false
                    self.lbl_afterbuy.alpha = 1
                    self.lbl_afterbuy.hidden = false

                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

                    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
                    break
                case .Failed:
                    btn_removeads.enabled = true
                    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
                    break
                case .Restored:
                    btn_removeads.enabled = true

                    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
                     SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
                    break
                default:
                    break
                }

            }
        }
    }
```